# Html Update the chart when button click

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 different charts (same type but showing different things) saved in 3 different indexes (indexsc/indexol/indexsa).

Is it possible to refresh or reload the page with the graph chosen from the button without have to open a new window each time?

My understanding of this is a core code calling 3 different sub code.

```
<form>
  <input type="button" value="Chart SC" onclick="window.open('indexsc.html', 'height=600, width=800, top=90, left=350, toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=yes, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, status=no');">

  <input type="button" value="Chart OL" onclick="window.open('indexol.html', 'height=600, width=800, top=90, left=350, toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=yes, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, status=no');">

  <input type="button" value="Chart SA" onclick="window.open('indexsa.html', 'height=600, width=800, top=90, left=350, toolbar=no, menubar=yes, location=yes, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, status=no');">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use iframe. with a combination of javascript of course. You can do it like this.

js

```
function getpage(y){

var x=y;

    if(x=="one"){

        document.getElementById("one").src="page4.html";
    }

    if(x=="two"){

        document.getElementById("two").src="page2.html";
    }

    if(x=="three"){

        document.getElementById("three").src="page3.html";
    }


}
```

html

```
<form>
  <input type="button" value="Chart SC" onClick="getpage('one')">

  <input type="button" value="Chart OL" onclick="getpage('two')"">

  <input type="button" value="Chart SA" onclick="getpage('three')"">

</form>


<div class="column">


<div class="row chartone">

<iframe id="one" src="page1.html" height="200" width="300"></iframe>

</div>


<div class="row charttwo">

<iframe id="two" src="page2.html" height="200" width="300"></iframe>

</div>

<div class="row chartthree">

<iframe id="three" src="page3.html" height="200" width="300"></iframe>

</div>

</div>
```

now you can manipulate your loading pages...when button clicked

vote if it helps